# Construction of a measure space from some weird functional

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Here is the complete problem I am trying to solve, but currently, I am just interested in proving that $\Sigma$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

> Let $X$ be a set and $\phi: 2^X \to [0, \infty]$ be a functional such that:
>
> - $\phi \varnothing = 0$.
> - $\phi(A \cup B) \ge \phi A + \phi B$, for all $A,B \subseteq X$ disjoint.
> - If $(A_n)$ is a non-increasing sequence of subsets of $X$ and $\phi A_0 < \infty$, then:
>
> $$\phi\left( \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n \right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \phi A_n$$
>
> - If $\phi A = \infty$, then for all $a \in \Bbb R$, there exists $B \subseteq A$ such that $a \le \phi B < \infty$
>
> Put:
>
> $$\Sigma = \{ E \subseteq X \mid \phi(A \cap E) + \phi(A \setminus E) = \phi A \text{ for every $A \subseteq X$} \}$$
>
> Show that $(X, \Sigma, \phi\mid_{\Sigma})$ is a measure space.

It is straightforward to prove that $\varnothing \in \Sigma$ and that for any $E \in \Sigma$, we have $X \setminus E \in \Sigma$.

So, basically my question is how to establish that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions. Here is what I did:

If $E, F \in \Sigma$, then for any $A \subseteq X$, we have:

$$\phi(A \cap (E \cup F)) = \phi( (A \cap (E \cup F)) \cap E) + \phi((A \cap (E \cup F) \setminus E) \\ = \phi(A \cap E) + \phi((A \setminus E) \cap F)$$

Hence,

$$\phi(A \cap (E \cup F)) + \phi(A \setminus (E \cup F)) = \phi(A \cap E) + \phi((A \setminus E) \cap F) + \phi((A \setminus E) \setminus F) \\ = \phi(A \cap E) + \phi(A \setminus E) = \phi A$$

and so $E \cup F \in \Sigma$.

Hence $\Sigma$ is closed under finite unions. Here's a bunch of possibly useful things as well:

- $\Sigma$ is also closed under set difference: if $E, F \in \Sigma$, then $X \setminus (E \setminus F) = (X \setminus E) \cup F \in \Sigma \implies E\setminus F \in \Sigma$.
- To prove $E \in \Sigma$, it is sufficient to verify that for any $A \subseteq X$, $\phi A \le \phi(A \cap E) + \phi(A \setminus E)$ because of the second property of $\phi$.
- $\phi$ is increasing (in the sense that if $A \subseteq B$, then $\phi A \le \phi B$).

For each $n \ge 0$, put $G_n = \cup_{m \le n} E_m$. We have that $(G_n) \subset \Sigma$ and for $A \subseteq X$, if it is true that for some $n_0 \in \Bbb N$, $\phi(A \setminus G_{n_0}) < \infty$, then we are done: using the third property of $\phi$ and that $(G_n)$ is increasing and that $\cup E_n = \cup G_n$, we have

$$\phi \left( A \setminus \bigcup_n E_n \right) = \phi \left( \bigcap_n (A \setminus G_n) \right) = \lim \phi(A \setminus G_n) \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$

also we have:

$$\phi \left( A \cap \bigcup_n E_n \right) \ge \lim \phi(A \cap G_n) \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$

Thus, the sum of the LHS's in $(1)$ and $(2)$ is $\ge \lim \{ \phi(A \setminus G_n) + \phi(A \cap G_n) \} = \phi A$.

> The other case is: for all $n \ge 0$, $\phi(A \setminus G_n) = \infty$.

Is there a way to finish the argument from here? Or would it be better to take a different approach?

**P.S.** For reference, this is problem $113Y(g)$ in Measure Theory by Fremlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notation: $Y^c= X$ \ $Y$ for $Y\subset X.$

To show that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions, once we know that $\Sigma$ is closed under finite unions and complements, it suffices to show that $\Sigma$ is closed under countable unions of pairwise disjoint collections.

Let $F=\{E_n\}_{n\in N}\subset \Sigma $ where $m\ne n \implies E_m\cap E_n=\emptyset.$

For $n \in N$ let $D_n=\cup_{j=1}^nE_j.$

For $A\subset X $ we have $\phi (A)=\phi (A\cap D_n)+\phi (A\cap D_n^c).$

For $A\subset X$ we have  $\phi (A\cap (\cup F) )\geq \phi (A\cap D_n)+\phi (A\cap \cup_{j>n}E_j).$

For $A\subset X$ we have $ A\cap (\cup F)^c=\cap_{n\in N}(A\cap D_n^c) . $ And since $A\cap D_{n+1}^c\subset A\cap D_n^c$ we have $\phi (B\cap (\cup F)^c)=\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi (B\cap D_n^c)$ whenever  $B\subset A$ and $\phi (B)<\infty.$

Therefore. with $\delta_n$ denoting a quantity that $\to 0$ as $n\to \infty,$ we have, for any $B\subset A$ such that $\phi (B)<\infty $ :$$\phi (B)\geq \phi (B\cap (\cup F))+\phi (B\cap (\cup F)^c)\geq$$ $$\geq \phi (B\cap D_n)+\phi (B\cap \cup_{j>n}E_n)+\phi (B\cap D_n^c)+\delta_n=$$ $$=[ \;\phi (B\cap D_n)+\phi (B\cap D_n^c)\;]+\phi (B\cap \cup_{j>n}E_j)+\delta_n=$$ $$=\phi (B)+\phi (B\cap \cup_{j>n}E_j)+\delta_n\geq$$ $$\geq  \phi (B)+\delta_n.$$ Letting $n\to \infty$ we have $$\phi(B)\geq \phi (B\cap (\cup  F))+\phi (B\cap (\cup F)^c)\geq \phi (B).$$  Now if $\phi (A)<\infty$ we can choose $B=A$ and we are done.

But if $\phi (A)=\infty$ then we can choose $B\subset A$ with $\phi (B)$ finite but as large as we like, and we have $$\phi (A)\geq \phi (A\cap (\cup F))+\phi (A\cap (\cup F)^c)\geq$$ $$\geq \sup \{\phi (B\cap (\cup F))+\phi (B\cap (\cup F)^c) :B\subset A \land \phi (B)<\infty \}=$$ $$=\sup \{\phi (B): B\subset A \land  \phi (B)<\infty \}=\infty =\phi (A).$$

Comment: Sorry .I fixed it to cover all cases.

Comment: I'd like to see a non-trivial  example of this functional, if you have one.

Comment: It turned out that it has a special name already: "inner measure". I found about it later through a quite extensive search. As for an example, I recently asked a question (with no answers yet) which involves a method to construct an inner measure given any measure space. The Wikipedia article gives something similar but it is quite easy to see why it is an inner measure. The one in my question is more special and trickier to prove: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868597/proving-that-a-mapsto-sup-mu-e-mid-a-supset-e-in-sigma-mu-e-infty