# Proving that $A \mapsto \sup\{ \mu E \mid A \supset E \in \Sigma, \mu E < \infty\}$ is an inner measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and define $m: 2^X \to [0,\infty]$ by $m A = \sup\{ \mu E \mid A \supset E \in \Sigma, \mu E < \infty\}$.

Show that $m$ is an [inner measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_measure).

There are $4$ axioms to be checked, three of which are pretty easy to do. Hence, I am just looking for a proof that:

> If $(A_n)$ is a non-increasing sequence of subsets of $X$, such that $m A_0 < \infty$, then:
>
> $$m\left( \bigcap_{n \in \Bbb N} A_n \right) \ge \lim_{n \to \infty} mA_n$$

Some thoughts: Note that $m$ is increasing. Now if $(A_n)$ is such a sequence, then for each $n$, there exists some $E_n \subset A_n$, with $E_n \in \Sigma$ and $\mu E_n < \infty$, such that:

$$mA_n - \frac1{1+n} \le \mu E_n \tag 1$$

Maybe I am heading in the wrong direction, but the problem now is to somehow modify the above in order to get a decreasing sequence $(E_n)$. I tried to do this in several ways but I couldn't.

**Update:** I figured out a solution in the case where $\mu X< \infty$: when this is the case, we have for any $D \in \Sigma$, $mD = \mu D$. Now for each $n$, put:

$$F_n = \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} E_k$$

$(F_n)$ is decreasing and $\mu F_0 = m F_0 \le m A_0 < \infty$. Hence, from $(1)$,

$$\lim m A_n \le \lim \mu E_n \le \lim \mu F_n = \mu \left( \bigcap_n F_n \right) = m \left( \bigcap_n F_n \right) \le m \left( \bigcap_n A_n \right)$$

Does anyone have an idea how to tackle the case $\mu X = \infty$?